How to send TFS mapped folder path to DTE View.TfsHistory command
I am using Visual Commander Extension for Visual Studio 2022. If I use this code below the TFS History window is getting opened but it is empty (no source location and no changeset items are shown).
What i get - TFS History window in VS 2022:

using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
 
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.TfsHistory");
    }
}

After I get the TFS History window and manually enter the source location path of course that it works. However I want when the TFS History window will open the location path to be already there with the corresponding changesets shown.
If I use this code:
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.TfsHistory", "C:\\Projects\\FS\\Some_Source_Path\\Source code");
    }
}

I get error:

system.runtime.interopservices.COMException (0x80004005)

Image of the error:

